# Why does the Delphi XE2 IDE crash in msimg32.dll?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-xe2

After installation of the Update 3 for Delphi XE2 I get the following error and the IDE does not want to start.

[image: The error]

I tried installing the standard Delphi XE2 with Update 1 and the problem persists. Do you have any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Did you have IdeFixPack installed? Did you ask Emba?

Comment: it seems that msimg32.dll is the extension component for Windows GDI that contains new APIs to improve the GDI32 functionality...probably a QC will resolve the issue...also, reinstalling the dll may probably solve the problem

Comment: I tried it. Additionally, it returns an error by the code of 0xc0000142 . What does that mean?

Comment: @KenWhite, the error message is `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142). Click OK to close the application. `

Comment: @KenWhite, the problem's persisting with Update 1 too, while it didn't happen before.

Comment: Are you using Windows 7 or Vista?

Comment: Done. I'm going to clean up some of the comment clutter, as I added a lot of it to the answer so it was in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file got corrupted somehow. I just checked my Win 7 64-bit Pro, and there are two copies of `msimg32.dll` found, 1 each in System32 and SysWOW64, both dated 7/13/2009 and version 6.1.7600.16385. So it appears they haven't been updated recently.

The actual error message you're getting is related to `access denied`, and the second one is `DLL initialization failed`, which is probably a result of the first one; the IDE isn't loading because the DLL can't be loaded.

My only suggestions are: 1) open a support case with [Embarcadero](http://support.embarcadero.com) (as an installation related problem, the support is free), or 2) reinstall Delphi from scratch, run it once to create registry entries, and then reinstall Update 3. I don't think anyone here is going to be much help; I'm not finding anything in searches related to Update 3 and this dll, so it seems to be just you having the issue.

Comment: You might also add the note about the [`IDEFixPack update`](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/2011/12/ide-fix-pack-4-6-supports-xe2-update-3/) for those who are using it and will have the problems with the `Delphi XE2 Update 3` ;)

Comment: ;) I think you just did. I didn't mention it, because I didn't know about it until your comment.

Comment: So nobody reads the Release Notes that come with the updates :-(

Comment: @Andreas, I just haven't done Update 3 yet (D2007 is still the primary version at my office, and I haven't had time yet to deal with the update installation). I actually always (well, almost always <g>) read the release notes. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete msimg32.dll in delphi_install_dir\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\bin folder.
This file shouldn't be there if you are doing everything correctly.